# Добавление участников сервера дискорда в базу данных

Tags: python, discord.py

У меня есть база данных, созданная с помощью SQLite3, также у меня есть айди сервера. Как при запуске бота, добавить всех членов сервера в таблицу?
Пример:

```
for i in ВСЕ УЧАСТНИКИ СЕРВЕРА:
   #Записывание участника в таблицу
```

Расширенный код:

```
  @bot.event
    async def on_ready():
        cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
        id INT,
        name TEXT,
        cash INT,
        mes INT
        )""")
        for member in bot.get_all_members():
            if cursor.execute(f'SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = {member.id}').fetchone() is None:
                cursor.execute(f'INSERT INTO users VALUES ({member.id},"{member}",{5},{0})')
        connection.commit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В событии on_ready просто пройдитесь for'ом по всем членам сообщества, например, так:

```
for member in bot.get_all_members():
```

Какие поля в вашей таблице будут, вы не написали. Если у вас таблица уже создана, то с помощью курсора добавьте:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table (id, ...) VALUES (?, ...)", member.id)
db.commit()
```

Потом из базы данных будете просто извлекать id пользователей и получать объекты класса Member с помощью `guild.fetch_member(id)`

Comment: К сожалению, мой бот добавляет только себя самого и человека, который написал сообщение, а не всех участников. К вопросу я добавил более расширенный код.

Comment: Что значит участник, который написал сообщение, если событие вызывается при запуске бота, а не при сообщении. И да, такое замечание: формат-строка в sqlite3 не очень безопасна, поэтому лучше использовать встроенный функционал (т.е. как я показал в ответе)

Comment: Я написал ровно то, что и вы написали. На сервере находилось 5 человек, бот при запуске, добавил только себя, а всех остальных нет.

Comment: Забыл коммит сделать, изменил ответ

Comment: да, это должно помочь, но тем не менее, бот видит из участников сервера только себя, тоесть он видит все сервера, на которые он подключен, но видит из участников только себя.

Comment: А вы включали в intents members?

Comment: включил и все заработало, спасибо!